# Unsure what's causing this Null Reference Exception when the logic is duplicated for a different control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I toggle the appearance a Button based on whether it can be clicked or not bfrom the `ViewModel`'s properties:

```
<Button Content="Test Connection" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="314,108,0,0" Name="btnTestConnection" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="3" Command="{Binding Path=TestCmd, Source={StaticResource fpvmObj}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=someObj}">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanButtonExecute, Source={StaticResource fpvmObj}}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanButtonExecute, Source={StaticResource fpvmObj}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="CornflowerBlue" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

`CanButtonExecute` is defined in the `ViewModel` like so:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public bool CanButtonExecute
{
    get { return canButtonExecute; }
    private set
    { 
        canButtonExecute = value;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CanButtonExecute"));
    }
}
```

This all works. My button will toggle from Gray to Blue as I fill in the values on the form. Simple enough, right? I figured from here, I could enable / disable 2 `DatePicker` controls based on the state of a `Checkbox` like so:

```
<DatePicker Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="314,41,0,0" Name="dpStartDate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="147" SelectedDate="{Binding dpStartDate, Source={StaticResource fpvmObj}}">
    <DatePicker.Style>
        <Style TargetType="DatePicker">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding chkSpecifyDateRange, Source={StaticResource fpvmObj}}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
                    <Setter Property="SelectedDate" Value="" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding chkSpecifyDateRange, Source={StaticResource fpvmObj}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="CornflowerBlue" />
                    <Setter Property="SelectedDate" Value="{Binding dpStartDate, Source={StaticResource fpvmObj}}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.Style>
</DatePicker>
```

Then back in the `ViewModel`:

```
public bool chkSpecifyDateRange
{
    get { return obj.SpecifyDateRange; }
    set 
    { 
        obj.SpecifyDateRange = value;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("chkSpecifyDateRange"));
    }
}
```

But this crashes and `PropertyChanged` is null, causing a Null Reference Exception. I'm not very familiar with `INotifyPropertyChanged` but no where in my `ViewModel` do I assign `PropertyChanged` a value; I always just call that last line in my `CanButtonExecute` setter, so I'm not really sure why this is a problem.

Comment: You **must not** invoke the events directly, you **must always** check if it is non-null before invoking it. If there is no event handler hooked up to it, it will be null. Do: `var evt = PropertyChanged; if (evt != null) evt(this, ...);`. The normal way to raise events is to write an event invocation method with the previous lines of code, called `OnPropertyChanged`, passing in the necessary parameters.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks, this solved the problem but I still don't really understand why I need to check if `PropertyChanged` is null for this case but it wasn't problematic for `CanButtonExecute`.

Comment: If the event is null, no event handler is hooked up to it. If it is non-null, there is an event handler hooked up to it. Obviously, you have an event handler in one case, and not in the other.

Comment: Well, right, but if all I'm *ever* doing is just calling `PropertyChanged(this, new ...("someProperty")`, why is it null in some cases and not others?

Comment: @sab669 I have addressed your last comment in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you implement INotifyPropertyChanged like :

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged { ... }
```

Always check for null value before raising event. Correct pattern is :

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public bool chkSpecifyDateRange
    {
        get { return obj.SpecifyDateRange; }
        set 
        { 
            obj.SpecifyDateRange = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("chkSpecifyDateRange"));
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
           PropertyChanged(sender, args);
    }
```

At the time of starting, default value is used. So, it appears working. Try changing the value of CanButtonExecute within your viewmodel as you have made it's set accessor private, you will get same NullReferenceException. Implement INotifyPropertyChanged and your errors will go away. Implementing is must, as it is used by Binding mechanism.